# Getting value from two checkboxes and inserting into mysql

Tags: php, loops, checkbox

I have run into a problem... I have a pair of checkboxes that I have named and numbered. I need to get the checkboxes marked and insert them into my database. Here is how I am creating the checkboxes:

```
<div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="acharge1" value="1"> <span style="color: #0C0">$$</span><input type="checkbox" name="amenities1" value="1">Amenity 1</div>
<div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="acharge2" value="1"> <span style="color: #0C0">$$</span><input type="checkbox" name="amenities2" value="1">Amenity 2</div>
<div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="acharge3" value="1"> <span style="color: #0C0">$$</span><input type="checkbox" name="amenities3" value="1">Amenity 3</div>
<div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="acharge4" value="1"> <span style="color: #0C0">$$</span><input type="checkbox" name="amenities4" value="1">Amenity 4</div>
```

Some of these will be checked and some wont. Also they will not always be checked in pairs, but I have to upload them in pairs to my database. So in other words: acharge1 and amenities1 will not be checked but acharge2 and amenities2 will be. So I tried a foreach loop and that did not work. I also tried a while loop, but I did not know what to check. So this is what I have now:

```
$aa = 1;
    echo "Amenity: ".$_POST['amenities'.$aa];
    $aa++;
    while(isset($_POST['amenities'.$aa])){
        $amen = $_POST['amenities'.$aa];
        if(isset($_POST['acharge'.$aa])){
        $acharge = $_POST['acharge'.$aa];
        }else{
            $acharge = "0";
            }
        echo "Amen: ". $amen." charge: ".$acharge;  
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO hotel_amenities (amenity_code, hotel_id, charge) VALUES ('$amen','$hotel_id','$acharge')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo $aa;
        $aa++;
        }
```

But as you can see this does not work, because if amenities1 is not checked it will not do the while loop through the others. Anyway ANY help on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT** This is the concept, so as you can see that sometimes they money box will be checked with the amenity and sometimes it will not.
http://www.cancunelitetravel.com/ale/Capture.PNG

Comment: They have to be inserted in the same row in mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are going about this is entirely wrong. If you are unsure of the number of options available, you should write it like this:

```
$cnt = 0;
foeach ($_POST as $option => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/(?:acharge|amenities)(\\d+)/", $option, $matches)) {
        $cnt = max($cnt, intval($matches[1]));
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i ++) {
    $amenity = $_POST['amenities' . $i];
    $value = "0";
    if (array_key_exists("acharge" . $i, $_POST)) {
        $value = "1";
    }
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hotel_amenities (amenity_code, hotel_id, charge) VALUES ('$amenity','$hotel_id','$value')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I think this would do it for you. That is assuming you have established the connection previously and taken care of the value for `$hotel_id`.

Comment: this is not exactly right, $amen was the other input checkbox, that I need to get. They are two. One is for a hotel amenity and the other is a checkbox right next to it, that implies if it will be charged extra or not.

Comment: I added an image to gt a better idea. Thanks so much!

Comment: I tried this and get an error: Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\olympus-backend\inc\add-hotel.php on line 79

Comment: Sorry, forgot to box the regular expression. Will edit the answer to a better one now.

Comment: By the way, this will insert the same value for `amenity_code`, seeing that the `value` attribute of the `aminitiesxx` in your HTML is always `1`. If that is not correct, you should change it.

Comment: :) I hope you can get some sleep now. I just turned off my light, so maybe I can get some too.

Comment: I am sorry I need a little bit more help, it is not working I thought it was.. but the amenities input has a value that also needs to be imported into the database and it is only importing a number that is incrementing. Sorry!

Comment: Ok I got the fix just had to add an if(isset($_POST['amenities'.$i])){ then it would run the code..}. Thanks again for all your help and have a great night!